# Permission denied when trying to get remote access via SSH

Tags: ssh, raspbian

I'm trying to access my RaspBerry Pi via ssh using Openssh but I keep getting permission denied when when I try to access from my laptop. I'm in the local network. I've checked the PAM is activated. This is my auth.log:

```
May 12 02:24:42 raspberrypi sshd[1746]: Invalid user agustin from 
192.168.1.101 port 60224
May 12 02:24:42 raspberrypi sshd[1746]: input_userauth_request: invalid 
user agustin [preauth]
May 12 02:24:46 raspberrypi sshd[1746]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; 
user unknown
May 12 02:24:46 raspberrypi sshd[1746]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): 
authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= 
rhost=192.168.1.101
May 12 02:24:48 raspberrypi sshd[1746]: Failed password for invalid user 
agustin from 192.168.1.101 port 60224 ssh2
```

This is my sshd_config:

```
Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none


# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in 
/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues 
 with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
ww#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
AllowUsers agustin
```

Comment: Provide the contents of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: I just updated my answer with the sshd_config

Comment: Not the auth log but the configuration file for `ssh`which is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Yes! Sorry i just edited again the answer

Answer (score 1):

The log message indicates that the user either doesn't exist or is not set up properly. If this is a local user you should be able to see it using `getent passwd augustin`. Verify that the user has a valid shell and their home directory exists.

You should also be able to `su` to the user as root on the machine.

If this is not a local user, likely pam is not set up correctly.